# How to add values from one column to another table using join?

Tags: python

I am having difficulties in merging 2 tables. In fact, I would like add a column from table B into table A based on one key

Table A (632 rows) contains the following columns:
part_number / part_designation / AC / AC_program

Table B (4,674 rows) contains the following columns:
part_ref / supplier_id / supplier_name / ac_program

I would like to add the supplier_name values into Table A

I have succeeded compiling a left joint based on the condition tableA.part_number == tableB.part_ref

However, when I look at the resulting Table, additional rows were created. I have now **683** rows instead of the initial **632** rows in Table A. How do I keep the same number of rows with including the supplier_name values in Table A? Below is presented a graph of my transformations:
[image]

Here is my code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Table B seems to contain duplicates (part_ref). The join operation creates a new record in your original table for each duplicate in Table B

```
import pandas as pd
print(len(pd.unique(updated_ref_table.part_ref)))
print(updated_ref_table.shape[0])
```

Comment: I renamed part_ref to be part_number but I still have the additional rows that I don't want. In fact I want the resulting table to contain the same number of rows than in Table A (632 rows) with the supplier_name column included.

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. Please check whether the column part_ref in table b contains duplicates. (See answer edit)

if both number are unequal, you have a problem.